# How to submit and validate a multipart/form-data form with a file upload in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, axios, symfony4

I am trying to upload a file via axios/ajax.
I am uploading the file like so:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('logoFile', e.files[0]);

axios.post('/startups/logo', formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
})
```

Then on Symfony 4, I want to hydrate my entity and validate the form created with formType:

My formType:

```
class LogoType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Remember username is email
        $builder
            ->add('logoFile', VichFileType::class, [
                'label'         => false,
                'required'      => false,
                'allow_delete'  => false,
                'download_uri'  => true,
                'download_label' => true,
                'download_link' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }
}
```

But in my controller, I can never validate the form:

```
public function updateLogo(Request $request): Response
{

    $image = $request->files->get('logoFile');

    if(!$image instanceof UploadedFile) {
        throw new HttpException(400, "Cannot find a file to upload. Try again.");
    }
    //$image is now an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile
    // THIS WORKS ^^ dd($image) does show the file properly

    $logo = new Logo();
    $form = $this->createForm(LogoType::class, $logo);
    $form->submit($request->files->all());

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
      // THIS PART NEVER GETS HIT.
    }
```

Note that trying to do `$form->handleRequest($request);` doesn't work nor does `$form->submit($request->request->all());` which is normally the way to go to validate forms submitted via ajax.

Does anyone know how to validate a form that has a file set with multipart/form-data ?

Thank you all.

Comment: What is var_dump($form->isSubmitted()) and var_dump($form->isValid()) giving you?

Comment: Thank you Blackbam for your comment, it is giving me true and false, the form is being submitted but it isn't valid.